# Updated pom.xml file not adding new libraries to project

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have created a maven project and added a few dependencies. Later I have included

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.18</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.18</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.18</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.18</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.18</version>
</dependency>
```

but these libraries are not being added to the project. How can I rectify this?

Comment: Please post your whole POM and highlight or add markers around the dependencies you have added.

Comment: Also elaborate your question. Are you seeing any exceptions when you run `mvn compile/install/package` or getting build errors in your IDE (e.g. eclipse)?

Comment: I have added few other dependencies along with these and eclipse have downloaded them but the above 5 dependencies are not being added..